# aggregating elements to create groups of minimal size

Tags: r, vector

I have the following sample vector:

```
v = c(3, 23, 224, 124, 49)
```

representing the number of elements in a corresponding list.

I would like to create groups of at least 50 elements based on the following criteria:

1. if a group is already larger than 50, I prefer not to touch it.
2. I can group only adjacent elements.

So in this case, I start by summing 3 and 23, and I am still not at 50. So I add the 26 to 224 (although I preferred not to do that based on Rule 1). So after the first iteration I have `c(250, 124, 49)`. But I still have the 49. So I group 49 to 124, again against the first rule - I don't have another choice, and the final output is:

```
v_f = c(250, 173)
```

How do I do this automatically and efficiently in R?

Comment: so the order is not important? Since we are capping it at 50 I would have thought to have output as `c(250, 124, 49)`

Comment: The groups have to be 50 or larger

Comment: What would be your output when you have input as `v = c(3, 23, 224, 124, 49, 100)` ?

Comment: I would prefer to add the 49 to the smaller group, that is: c(250, 124, 149)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

We initiate a cumulative sum `j`, starting at `0`, a grouping value `k`, starting at `1` and a group vector `w`, set to `NA` with length = `length(v)`.

```
j <- 0
k <- 1
w <- rep(NA, length(v))
```

Now we loop over `i = 1:length(v)`, setting the grouping value `k` in group vector `w` at position `i`, add the current value of `v[i]` to `j`, and add up `k` when `j` is `>= 50`, resetting `j` to `0`. If the last group does not fill up to 50, reset all values of the last group in grouping vector `w` to the value `k-1`:

```
for(i in 1:length(v)){
  w[i] <- k
  j <- j + v[i]
  if(i == length(v) & j < 50){
    w[w == k] <- k-1
  }
  if(j >= 50){
    k <- k + 1
    j <- 0
  }
}
```

Example:

```
v = c(3, 23, 224, 124, 49, 17, 3, 8, 12)
> w
[1] 1 1 1 2 3 3 3 3 3

df <- cbind.data.frame(v, w)
    v w
1   3 1
2  23 1
3 224 1
4 124 2
5  49 3
6  17 3
7   3 3
8   8 3
9  12 3
```

Now we can `aggregate` over the group to get the cumulative sums:

```
aggregate(v ~ w, df, sum)
  w   v
1 1 250
2 2 124
3 3  89
```

Answer (score 1):

I could not come up with a pretty R-function.. so here's a for-loop

```
v = c(3, 23, 224, 124, 49)

#initilise
result <- c()
loopcounter = 0; sum = 0; cumsum_threshold = 50

#loop through v
for (i in v) {
  #calculate the cumulative sum
  sum = i + sum
  #if cumsum > 50
  if (sum >= cumsum_threshold ) {
    #pass to result-vector
    result[ length( result ) + 1 ] <- sum
    #reset cumsum to 0
    sum <- 0
  }
  #increase loopcounter
  loopcounter = loopcounter + 1
  #when at the end of v, AND sum < threshold
  if ( loopcounter == length( v ) & sum < cumsum_threshold ) {
    #add sum to last entry of result-vector
    result[ length( result ) ] <- result[ length( result) ] + sum
  }
}

result
#[1] 250 173
```